# « En immédiat/urgent » : formulation ?

Tags: prépositions, adverbes, formulation

Le dialogue qui suit pourrait constituer un divulgâcheur.

> — Le Président me demande de renforcer la posture. C'est-à-dire : un
>   sous-marin nucléaire lanceur d'engins à l'eau, *en immédiat*.
>
> ---
>
> — On casse son fil. Lancez une torpille... On lance *en urgent*. Tube
>   2. Azimut 0-5-9.
>
> [ Extraits de dialogue dans Le chant du loup (2019, Abel
>   Lanzac/Antonin Baudry) ]

- Quel est le nom sous-jacent qualifié par *immédiat* et *urgent*, le cas échéant ; s'agit-il toujours du même nom dans ce genre d'emploi ?
- Quelle est la différence d'avec l'adverbe (*urgemment, immédiatement, maintenant*) voire avec le nom (*en toute urgence*) ; peut-on qualifier l'emploi de la tournure avec la préposition [*en*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/en/0) ici (nature, fonction, registre etc.) ?

Answer (score 2):

Pour moi, c'est un raccourci pour :

- en mode immédiat
- en mode urgent

Je n'ai pas vu le film, mais je crois comprendre qu'il s'agit d'un film de guerre, c'est peut-être une manière de rendre le style et la syntaxe télégraphiques du langage militaire.